# ajax with .done callback inside loop

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have to loop through a lot of data and send it to the server in packages. On success I want to use the response data in the callback from the ajax function to show some status updates on the site.

the following code seems not to work because you're not supposed to make functions in loops:

```
for (...) {
   ajaxCall().done(function(response) {
      system.log(response);
   });
}
```

But, when defining the function outside of the loop, the response parameter does not get recognized by the function.

Comment: You can make functions in a loop. That is one man's opinion. You can always use a named function, should work exactly the same.